# Custom STL List implemenation questions

Tags: c++, stl

Okay, So I've been working on some book examples and stuff and found this exercise to implement the STL List lookalike. I've made it somehow and it kinda works, but I've got some major flaws in the implementation. 
 The biggest one is that I have totally no idea how to make my List.end() iterator to work as it's supposed to do. 
I guess I'll show the code first and try to tell some of my ideas next.

```
    #ifndef TESTS_LST_H
    #define TESTS_LST_H

    #include <memory>
    #include <cstddef>

    template<class T> class Node;
    template<class T> class ListIter;

    template<class T>
    class List {
    public:
    typedef ListIter<T> iterator;
    typedef const ListIter<T> const_iterator;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;


    List(): first(0), last(0), sz(0) {}
    List(const List<T>& lst);
    ~List() { clear(); }

    iterator begin() { return iterator(first); }
    iterator end()   { return iterator(last); }
    iterator insert() {}
    iterator erase() {}
    const_iterator begin() const { return iterator(first); }
    const_iterator end() const   { return iterator(last); }

    void push_back(const T& val);
    void push_front(const T& val);
    void clear();
    void pop_front();
    void pop_back();
    size_type size() { return sz; }
    bool empty() { return sz == 0; }


    List& operator=(const List& l);
    private:
        Node<T>* first;
    Node<T>* last;
    size_type sz;

    std::allocator<Node<T>>* alloc;
    };

    template<class T>
    class Node {
    public:
        Node(): next(0), prev(0), value(0) {}
        Node(const T& val): next(0), prev(0), value(val) {}

    private:
        Node<T>* next;
        Node<T>* prev;
        T value;

    friend class List<T>;
    friend class ListIter<T>;
    };

    template<class T>
    class ListIter {
    public:
    typedef ListIter<T> iterator;

    ListIter(Node<T>* iter): current_node(iter) {}
    ListIter(): current_node(0) {}
    ListIter(ListIter<T>* iter): current_node(iter->current_node) {}

    inline T& operator*() { return current_node->value; }
    iterator& operator=(const iterator& rhs) { *this->current_node = rhs.current_node; }
    bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) { return current_node->value == rhs.current_node->value; }
    bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) { return current_node->value != rhs.current_node->value; }
    iterator& operator++();
    iterator operator++(int);
    iterator& operator--();
    iterator operator--(int);

    private:
        Node<T>* current_node;
        friend class List<T>;
    };

    template<class T>
    void List<T>::push_back(const T& val)
    {
    Node<T>* temp = alloc->allocate(1);
    alloc->construct(temp, val);
    if (first == 0) {
        first = last = temp;
    } else {
        temp->prev = last;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
    sz++;
    }

    template<class T>
    void List<T>::push_front(const T &val)
    {
        Node<T>* temp = alloc->allocate(1);
        alloc->construct(temp, val);
    if (first == 0) {
        first = last = temp;
    } else {
        temp->prev = 0;
        temp->next = first;
        first->prev = temp;
        first = temp;
    }
    sz++;
    }

    template<class T>
    void List<T>::clear()
    {
        Node<T>* current = first;
        while (current != 0) {
        Node<T>* next = current->next;
        //delete current
        alloc->deallocate(current, 1);
        alloc->destroy(current);
        current = next;
    }
    first = last = 0;
    sz = 0;
    }

    template<class T>
    List<T>::List(const List &lst)
    {
    first = last = 0;
    sz = 0;
    for (auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); it++) {
        push_back(it.current_node->value);
    }
    push_back(lst.last->value);
    }

    template<class T>
    List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List &lst)
    {
    first = last = 0;
    sz = 0;
    for (auto it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it) {
        push_back(it.current_node->value);
    }
    push_back(lst.last->value);
    return *this;
    }

template<class T>
void List<T>::pop_front()
{
    first = first->next;
    alloc->deallocate(first->prev, 1);
    alloc->destroy(first->prev);
    first->prev = 0;
    sz--;
}

template<class T>
void List<T>::pop_back()
{
    last = last->prev;
    alloc->deallocate(last->next, 1);
    alloc->destroy(last->next);
    last->next = 0;
    sz--;
}

template<class T>
ListIter<T>& ListIter<T>::operator++()
{
    current_node = current_node->next;
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
ListIter<T>& ListIter<T>::operator--()
{
    current_node = current_node->prev;
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
ListIter<T> ListIter<T>::operator++(int)
{
    iterator tmp(*this);
    ++*this;
    return tmp;
}

template<class T>
ListIter<T> ListIter<T>::operator--(int)
{
    iterator tmp(*this);
    --*this;
         return tmp;
    }

    #endif //TESTS_LST_H
```

As you can see .end() function returns a regular last element of the list and not the one past the end as it should. 
 Should I try to rework this part to possibly keep the *last as the one past the end iterator and use the operator+ to iterate through the list to omit the need in the pointer to the end of the actual list? 
 Something like this (not sure about the corectness of the code below):

```
iterator& operator+(std::size_type n) 
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ++*this;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

But I'm not sure that's how the stuff works in the actual implementation, loops could be very demanding after all. 

 I know that this stuff is already out there and works and all that. That's just for the educational purposes, so I hope to hear some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator were known in the past as "smart pointer", since they works like that. (Indeed, pointers are iterators, but not the opposed). So, think an iterator like a pointer.

"One past the end" is clear what means when you are working with vectors: a `vector` contains its elements in contiguous space. Indeed, it is possible to implement vector iterator with just pointers. But that is not the case for a linked `list`, where generally its element are not in contiguous memory.

Because you implemented the `List` class as a doubled linked list, I suggest you to change the `first` and `last` pointers by a head:

```
template<class T>
class List {
// ...
private:
    Node<T> head;
    size_type sz;
};
```

So, the `begin()` iterator become `head.next` and `end()` iterator become `&head`. This works as far the last element in the list points to the `head`.

BTW: You don't need to create `Node<T>` as a `class` with friends classes. It is just an implementation detail. Change it to a `struct` and put it in a implementation `namespace`.